# How does a decaying learning rate schedule with AdamW influence the weight decay parameter?

Tags: python, optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

According to the Pytorch documentation

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.AdamW.html

the AdamW optimiser computes at each step the product of the learning rate gamma and the weight decay coefficient lambda. The product

gamma*lambda =: p

is then used as the actual weight for the weight decay step. To see this, consider the second line within the for-loop in the AdamW algorithm:

[image]

But what if the learning rate lambda shrinks after each epoch because we use (say) an exponential learning rate decay schedule? Is p consistently computed using the *initial* learning rate lambda and thus p stays constant during the whole training process? Or does p shrink dynamically as lambda shrinks due to an implicit interaction with the the learning rate decay schedule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `torch.optim._functional.adamw` is called each time you step the optimizer *using the current parameters of the optimizer* (that call occurs at [torch/optim/adamw.py:145](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e1b84e1b6bd688c7b3bff3e7742c1f8875966e6e/torch/optim/adamw.py#L145)). This is the function that actually updates the model parameter values. So after a learning-rate scheduler changes the optimizer parameters, the steps afterwards will use those parameters, not the initial ones.

To verify this, the product is recomputed at each step in the code at [torch/optim/_functional.py:137](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/a9c7d626e1d483548ec686cef517edecdf543be0/torch/optim/_functional.py#L137).

Comment: Thank you for this answer which I accepted as correct. Note however that optimiser.state_dict() shows that the optimiser has an "lr" parameter as well as an "initial_lr" parameter and both of these parameters are accessible during the whole training process (whereby only "lr" is shrinking after every epoch due to the learning rate decay schedule). Are you certain that torch.optim._functional.adamw is calling "lr" and not "initial_lr" ?

Comment: I agree that the code you sent suggests that "lr" is called and not "initial_lr". However, do you agree that it is pretty akward that this implies that it is impossible to simultaneously have a decaying learning rate and a constant weight decay coefficient? Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: There's only one `lr` per-group in AdamW optimizer. The only state dictionary that might contain `initial_lr` that I'm aware of is the learning-rate scheduler's state dictionary (set [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/dd1121435b14b48d862b5f16e4ce8b0d71f6dd5d/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py#L35) during the scheduler's initialization). This is required since often times the learning-rate at a particular time-step is easier computed as a function of the original.

Comment: If you print `AdamW([torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1))],lr=0.1).state_dict()` you should see only `lr` in the optimizers state dictionary. The initial value isn't stored because it's not used for anything in the optimizer itself.

Comment: I'm not by any means an expert in the AdamW optimizer so I'm not sure of the justification for the way it's implemented. That said, if you did want `lr*weight_decay` to remain constant then you could update `weight_decay` as well each time the learning-rate is updated so that the product is constant.

Comment: Worth pointing out that pytorch doesn't restrict you from what you *can* provide as optimizer parameters for each parameter group. So you can put whatever you want. E.g. `AdamW([{'initial_lr':2, 'gobldygook': 3, 'params':torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1))}],lr=0.1).state_dict()`. But if those parameters aren't ones that the optimizer cares about then it won't actually use them for anything.

Comment: Hmm I understand. But if you execute 

`compiled_optimiser = torch.optim.AdamW([torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1))], lr = 1, weight_decay = 0.01)`

`lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(compiled_optimiser, lr_lambda = lambda epoch: 1 , last_epoch = -1)`

`print(compiled_optimiser.state_dict())`

then you will in fact see the "initial_lr" attribute as part of the optimiser state because the learning rate scheduler wrapper has been applied. So in this sense "initial_lr" is part of `compiled_optimiser.state_dict()` and could in fact be called during the whole training process?

Comment: @Joker123 Ah yes. I miss-read that code that I had linked related to `initial_lr` earlier. The scheduler is actually storing `initial_lr` in the optimizer's state dict, not it's own. I'm not certain of the motivation for this decision, it would make more sense IMO for them to store that that info in the scheduler's state dict. Nonetheless, the optimizer doesn't use that information itself, it is only potentially used by the scheduler to update the learning rates.

Answer (score 0):

Based purely on the algo posted gamma and lambda and thus also their product p are constant.

Comment: But the algorithm takes the learning rate lambda as input and only describes what happens during one gradient update. It is not clear to me whether the lambda in the given algorithm is the initial (and thus fixed) learning rate or the decaying (and thus dynamic) learning rate.

Comment: If it was decaying wouldn't that be included as a line in the algorithm? Considering it's not I assume it's fixed but I've been wrong before...